# identify the last filled cell in column, and populate formula till the range end derived from the next column

Tags: excel, vba

i have data which would be added daily in worksheet. i want to populate a formula (Today/Value) in column X starting from the blank cell in X (i.e the new pasted data), till the end range of data identified from the next column.
my code is definately wrong 1. auto fill isnt happening. also it needs to be from empty cell of X

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("x4").End(xlDown).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Today()"

col = ActiveCell.Column

Range(col & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=Today()" `i identify the first blank cell in column x and want to populate formula (today) till the end range of total data i.e column B last line `

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Range("x4").End(xlDown).Offset(1), "X" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=Today()"

' Convert formula to value
With Application.Intersect(Range("W:X"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Range property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.range?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Sub Macro2()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Range("W1").End(xlDown).Offset(1), "W" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=Today()"
Range(Range("X1").End(xlDown).Offset(1), "X" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=IF(RC[-18]="""",""ask team to update"",IF(RC[-16]<>"""",TODAY()-RC[-16],TODAY()-RC[-18]))"

Range("W:X").Copy
Range("W:X").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

### Populate Datestamp For Newly Added Rows

The yellow color designates the initially empty cells.

[image]

It is assumed that the data has headers making the 4th row irrelevant.

```vb
Sub PopulateToday()
    
    Const DATE_COLUMN As Variant = "X" ' or 24
    Const COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 1 ' next column
    
    With ActiveSheet ' improve!
        Dim fcell As Range
        Set fcell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, DATE_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Dim lcell As Range
        Set lcell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns(DATE_COLUMN).Column _
            + COLUMN_OFFSET).End(xlUp).Offset(, -COLUMN_OFFSET)
        If fcell.Row <= lcell.Row Then .Range(fcell, lcell).Value = Date
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the query i finally am going with. thanks

```
Sub Macro2() 
Dim lastRow As Long 
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Range(Range("W1").End(xlDown).Offset(1), "W" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=Today()" 
Range(Range("X1").End(xlDown).Offset(1), "X" & lastRow).FormulaLocal = "=IF(RC[-18]="""",""ask team to update"",IF(RC[-16]<>"""",TODAY()-RC[-16],TODAY()-RC[-18]))" 
Range("W:X").Copy 
Range("W:X").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
End Sub
```